# How to deal with mocks in Mockito in different test classes?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I am trying to understand how Mockito works and I have come to one issue - I have two different test cases and I want to mock the same method from service but with different parameters. When I tried to do it like that:

```
@Test
public void firstTest() {
    Mockito.when(service.getValue("parameter1")).thenReturn(1);
}

@Test
public void secondTest() {
    Mockito.when(service.getValue("parameter2")).thenReturn(2);
}
```

I get an error:
[MockitoHint] 1. Unused... -> at path.getValue(MyTest.java:95)
[MockitoHint]  ...args ok? -> at path...

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? When I use Mockito.anyString() as an argument this is not happening anymore...

Mock class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

public class MyTest {

@Mock
private MyService myService;

...

@InjectMocks
private TestingService testingService = new TestingService();
}
```

Comment: Just a typo, I edited it

Comment: please add how you create the mock service and the class of it

Comment: Could it be possible that Mockito just wants to tell zou the mocked call was never used during the test, so you may have mocked the wrong method/parameter?

Answer (score 0):

you can use use Mockito argument matchers eq() method like below,

import the org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers

```
@Test
public void firstTest() {
    Mockito.when(service.getValue(eq("parameter1"))).thenReturn(1);
}

@Test
public void secondTest() {
    Mockito.when(service.getValue(eq("parameter2"))).thenReturn(2);
}
```

Comment: This is not working, I already tried that

Answer (score 0):

If your tests are literally as shown:

```
@Test
public void firstTest() {
    Mockito.when(service.getValue("parameter1")).thenReturn(1);
}

@Test
public void secondTest() {
    Mockito.when(service.getValue("parameter2")).thenReturn(2);
}
```

Then the problem is that you have mocked out a return value for a method call but done absolutely nothing that actually causes the methods to be called. So your mocking is "unused" and pointless.

Add to your tests to actually do something and verify behavior:

```
@Test
public void firstTest() {
    Mockito.when(service.getValue("parameter1")).thenReturn(1);

    // Do something with service that causes `getValue` to be called with "parameter1"

    assertThat(service.someOtherFunctionThatReturnsSomethingBasedOnGetValue()).isEqualTo(1);
}
```

Comment: No, I am calling the method later, I just didn't include it in my question

Comment: Then, for completeness and clarity, please post a complete example that illustrates exactly what you're doing and exactly what error you're getting and exactly where the error is showing up.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use a mock with literal arguments.
When you want to mock a method and act based on identified argument you need to use ArgumentCaptors

Take a look at this link
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/mockito-argumentcaptor-captor-annotation

In your case you should do something like

```
@Test
public void firstTest() {
    ArgumentCaptor acString = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    Mockito.when(service.getValue(acString.capture()))
        .thenReturn(chooseReturn(acString.value));

    // run code ...
    // assert ...
}

private int chooseReturn(String arg) {
    if (arg.equals("parameter1")) {
        return 1;
    } else if (arg.equals("parameter2")) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("cannot identify " + arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: "You cannot use a mock with literal arguments." - this is incorrect. [For example](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#10).

Comment: @dominicoder 
As far I know you cannot use a mock with direct values, you need to have an argument matcher, simplest case being something like `someMock.someMethod(eq("string"))`.
I might be wrong, happy to learn something new, but could you please provide a more useful link to prove your point? the link you sent is the full mockito documentation.

Comment: See item #10 in the link (I don't know why the anchor link doesn't work). - `when(mock.someMethod("some arg"))
   .thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
   .thenReturn("foo");`

Comment: thanks for this, I will try it out and figure out how this works. it might be that it was not possible in older mockito library but it is now